# Comparing specific items of lists

Tags: netlogo

I would like to compare items of lists, looking at specific items. My lists can differ in some items, but be the same in the first two or also in the last one (time), as shown below.

```
[(object 10) (owner 6) men 0.408 0.365 (time 3)]
```

and

```
[(object 10) (owner 6) men 0.408 0.364 (time 3)]
```

Using the following code:

```
    to-report count-dupl [ a-list ]

       let t_list remove-item 0 a-list
       set shift_list lput [-999] t_list  

       let dup_count 0
      (foreach my-list shift_list [ [ a b ] -> 
           show ( word " Comparing " a " to " b )
     if ( item 0 a = item 0 b or item 6 a = b or item 6 a + 1 = b) [ set dup_count (dup_count + 1) ] ])

    print word "Count duplicates: "  dup_count
    if-else ( dup_count > 0 ) [ report true ][ report false ]  
end
```

it does not return true if the first two elements or if the time factor and the time factor + 1 in the two lists are duplicates.
I would like to select items that are not consecutive and also that are not so close in time (i.e. that differ at least for 1 or 2 ticks - tick is item 6).

I hope you can help me.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that comparing item to whole list is what you want.

I'm no netlogo expert, but perhaps you want more `(` `)` parens in your initial `if` statement.
Or re-phrase as smaller tests:

```
    if (item 0 a = item 0 b) [ set dup_count (dup_count + 1) ]
    if (item 6 a = item 6 b) [ set dup_count (dup_count + 1) ]
    if (item 6 a + 1 = item 6 b) [ set dup_count (dup_count + 1) ]
```

It's hard to see how shifting the input list by one position is helpful.
It looks like the debug message shows a different list
from the one being compared.

The final `if-else` statement could be collapsed into
a single `report dup_count > 0`